# Generic inner class constructor accepts different type parameter what is set?

Tags: java, class, generics, constructor, nested

Apologies for the convoluted question, but I can't figure out an easier way to ask it. I am currently experimenting with generics and have run into something I cannot wrap my head around. I have a generic class with type parameter `T` and it has a generic inner class with type parameter `E`. However, the inner class' constructor requires a `T`.

If I instantiate the outer class with, say, `Outer<String>` and instantiate the inner class with `<Integer>`, and call its constructor using an integer, there is no problem. This does not make any sense to me, as in this case the constructor should only work with a `String` as is set in the `Outer` type parameter. Why is this the case?

If I create a method in the inner class that requires a `T`, though, `The method method(T) in the type Outer<T>.InnerGeneric<Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (int)` which does make sense to me. How come this does not happen with the constructor method?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
public class Outer<T> { 
    class InnerGeneric<E> { 
        InnerGeneric(T t) {
            //do something
        }

        void method(T t) {
            //do something
        }
    }

    class Inner {
    }

    Outer(T t) {
        InnerGeneric<T> inner1 = new InnerGeneric<>(t); 
        InnerGeneric<Integer> inner2 = new InnerGeneric<>(1); //i do not get any error here, 
                                                                and the code can run just                                                                 
                                                                fine with this, why???

        inner2.method(t);   
        inner2.method(1); //get a compilation error here, this makes sense to me   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer<String> outer = new Outer<>("Any string");        
    }
}
```

EDIT: I am using Eclipse, not sure about what that means in terms of what version of javac, as I am still fairly new to it all

Comment: Which version of javac are you using? Does it also happen if you use `<Integer>` instead of `<>`?

Comment: No repro with `javac` v`1.8.0_121`, I do get an error. Eclipse just compiles it though (if I remove the method call).

Comment: For me it hasn't sense either but shouldn't you parametrize the Inner class with T also?

Comment: By the way, apart from the missing information about compiler versions, it's a perfectly fine question, not convoluted at all. The fact that you included a code snippet that is complete, readable and produces the error described raises it above 90% of all the questions asked here. :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response guys! I am using eclipse, which, correct me if I am wrong, does not use the standard javac compiler? So this is why the error is only reproducible in Eclipse?

Comment: @CristiánRamón-Cortés the reason i parameterised the inner class with E was purely for experimental purposes as I was trying to understand generics further, and so i was basically just messing around seeing what was acceptable code when I ran into my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried it with javac 1.8.0_25 and it gives a compilation error, as you'd correctly expect, while Eclipse indeed does not. (I assume from the error message you quoted that it is Eclipse you're working with.)

This seems like a bug in the Eclipse compiler, specifically with the handling of the diamond operator. If you replace that line with `InnerGeneric<Integer> inner2 = new InnerGeneric<Integer>(1);` then Eclipse rejects it too.

*(Though my search skills aren't very good, as far as I can tell it hasn't been logged yet as an Eclipse bug, so you should probably report it.)*

Comment: Wow its exciting that I have perhaps found a bug! How do I go about reporting it? Perhaps someone with better experience should since I am still fairly new to java

Comment: You can do it [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi), the process should be fairly simple.